# Sharepoint Application Search doesn't work well for skills, interests

Tags: search, user-profile, my-site, user-profile-property

I have provisioned MySites and the Application Search Service. This works when finding people - I put in my name or name of a collegaue and it does give search results.

But when I'm trying to search using some properties, e.g. I have in my profile a set of skills - sharepoint, c# .. etc, and in find people I put "sharepoint" it doesn't provide any results. (I did crawl everything after I updated my profile). So on properties, like skills, interests it doesn't return any results.

What makes it more strange is that when I search for music preference ... which is a self-defined (custom) property which I've added to mysites profiles myself it does give results. E.G. I put dance music in music preference, I perform search for "music", and it finds me.

I really don't understand how is that possible and what did I miss? All those properties are indexed.

Anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

If u want to search custom property then u have to configure following Changes.

go to central admin > services > search service > menaged property >select your numeric field and edit it's propery

select those options

1)."Reduce storage requirements for text properties by using a hash for comparison"

2)."Allow this property to be used in scope"

after that must do full crawl

That's It.